# Greatest common divisors of some binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisors-multiples

This is cross-posted from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4603130/573047).

While making some computation, I stumbled upon a curious relation among some binomial coefficients.

Consider the sequence of binomial coefficients $a(k,n)$, $0 \le k \le n-1$, $n \ge 2$ defined as follows:

$$a(k,n) = \binom{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+3+k}{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor+1+k}$$

and the sequence ($n \ge 2$):

$$b_n=\gcd(a(0,n),a(1,n),\ldots,a(n-2,n),a(n-1,n))$$

I conjecture that:

$$b_n \gt 1 \space\space\space\space \forall n \ge 2$$

The first few values of $b_n$ starting from $b_2$ are $2,5,6,143,102,253,899,703$. It has been verified up to $n = 10000$ (see the answer to the linked math.stackexchange question).

Any hint for proving or disproving the conjecture?

Also, can we say something about the values of $b_n$?

I don't see an easy application of e.g. Kummer's theorem or Lucas's theorem.

I have had a partial answer at math.stackexchange (see link above) according to which the conjecture is probably true, and relates it to prime gaps conjectures.

Is that answer the best that we can say?